# Find the values of a solution of Burgers' equation, given its value at one point

Tags: partial-differential-equations

So I have the PDE:
$$u_t+u\cdot u_x=0$$With auxiliary condition $u(1,1)=5$. The question asks if one can find the value of the points at $(2,1), (2,2), (6,2), (4,3), (10,3), (11,3)$. The way I went about it is that my professor went through the solution of Burgers' Equation and reached a solution:
$$u(x,t) = \frac{x-x_0}{t} = g(x_0)$$
Now, I plugged in $(1,1)$ into $u$ to find that $x_0=-4$. Now noting that $g$ is supposed to be increasing, I found that every point is not possible to find a value for except the first point $(2,1)$, and the value there is $6$. Did I approach this question right? Or is there something lacking from my explanation?

Comment: You made a mistake. $x_0=4$ is false.

Comment: Could you let me know where?

Comment: Oh I meant $x_0=-4$.

Comment: @JJacquelin is my solution still correct?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot check your solution which isn't detailed enough.

Comment: @JJacquelin I'm sorry but how is it not detailed enough? I think I've specified how I got to my results very clearly...

Comment: You wrote " every point is not possible to find a value for except the first point (2,1)" Since you didn't detailed how you found this, It was not possible to see where is the mistake which makes partly false your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of Burgers' equation is constant on characteristic lines. Each characteristic line is of the form $x= x_0+ vt$ where $v$ is the value of solution on that line. Specifically, from $u(1,1)=5$ we get the line $x = 1 + 5(t-1)$, or simply $x=5t-4$.

Out of the given points $(x,t)$, namely $(2,1),(2,2),(6,2),(4,3),(10,3),(11,3)$, only $(6,2)$ and $(11,3)$ lie on the above line.  So we know that $u$ is equal to $5$ at those two points, and we don't know about the rest.

All of this is assuming that the line $x=5t-4$ does not hit a shock wave (at which characteristic lines terminate).